# Rails 5: add/edit multiple records in "has_many through" relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have classic `has_many through` relationship where I need to be able to **add multiple Companies to particular User**. Models look like this:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :accounts
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :accounts
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :accounts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: :accounts
end
```

In console I can add single record with this:

```
[1] pry(main)> user=User.find(7)
[2] pry(main)> user.accounts.create(company_id: 1)
```

**How do I add, edit, delete multiple accounts for user in one query?** I need to attach multiple Companies to User, then Edit / Remove if necessary.

So far I tried to implement array part [from this tutorial](https://ducktypelabs.com/how-a-has_many-through-association-works-in-practice), but somehow it does not work as obviously I'm doing something wrong here:

```
[4] pry(main)> user.accounts.create(company_id: [1,2])
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["email", "tester@gmaill.com"], ["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Account:0x00000005b2c640 id: nil, company_id: nil, user_id: 7, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

As I understand I need to create array somehow and then operate with that. I would appreciate any help here. Thank you!

**Solution**

If anyone needs, I solved my problem a bit differently. I used [checkboxes from this tutorial](https://makandracards.com/makandra/32147-rails-4-introduced-collection_check_boxes) and it works just fine for me.

Comment: Since, User has many Accounts, you can accept nested attributes for Accounts in User model. Now, Account belongs to Company and User. So, for Company,  you can provide a select box in the fields_for Account.

Comment: @prasad.surase Thank you. Yes, this could be something I can do. For now I was thinking, how do I write it in console to see it adds multiple Companies to User?

Comment: the [bulk_insert](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) gem can be used.

Comment: @maxple Thank you, didn't know about that. I expect for each User to have up to ~5 Companies. Not sure if this is "bulk_insert" case. Isn't there some relatively simple query to do the trick?

Comment: bulk_insert is relatively simple, in fact, compared to building a `INSERT TO` SQL statement by hand, which is something people sometimes do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with the [bulk_insert](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) gem:

```
company_ids = [1,2]
user_id = 1

Account.bulk_insert(
  values: company_ids.map do |company_id|
    {
      user_id: user_id,
      company_id: company_id,
      created_at: Time.now,
      updated_at: Time.now
    }
  end
)
```

Comment: Ok, I could try this. As I understand this would work for adding Companies to User. How I could do Edit, e.g., remove Company with ID=2 and add Company with ID=3 to User with ID=1 ? Can "bulk_insert" gem do some update action as well or for that I would do something else?

Comment: Deleting and creating in a single query is getting into more complex SQL than I'm familiar with.

Comment: There is already the `update_all` and `delete_all` in rails, there just isn't a similar one for inserts as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Yes, I'm  familiar with `update_all` - use that in one of my models and it works just fine. My initial thinking was to use this tagging approach - https://rubyplus.com/articles/4241-Tagging-from-Scratch-in-Rails-5 However so far I did not manage to have it working in my case.